# Postfixadmin does not work after update "Cannot redeclare hex2bin"

Tags: debian, php5, postfix

I had recently updated my Debian wheezy (7.7) and forgot to check all systems after that. So, I can't really say what the versions were before I upgraded or at which point it broke.

When I tried to connect to my postconf today I received nothing but a blank page. A look into the error log revealed this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare hex2bin() in /var/www/postconf/functions.inc.php on line 1338
```

If I attempted to call the login page directly into php with `php5 /var/www/postconf/login.php` the same error is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across [this old update](http://sourceforge.net/p/postfixadmin/mailman/message/28661498/) from the postfixadmin people that described that "PHP around 5.3.8 includes hex2bin as native function". Fortunately the PHP function apparently does the same as the postconf function so its save to use theirs.

You have to edit `/var/www/postconf/functions.inc.php` and navigate to the hex2bin function in line 1328 and enter this line in front of the function: `if (!function_exists('hex2bin')) {` and close that bracket at the end of the function (line 1339) with `}`.

After that postconf will work as expected.

Most likely it would be better to update the whole `/var/www/postconf` folder, but I could not figure out how to do this.